# ThrowHelper extensions are leading to the DoesNotReturn method when they throw as opposed to staying on the line that threw it

Tags: c#, .net

When I'm debugging and an assertion throws, e.g. the one below, then the debugger takes me to:

[image]

instead of staying on the same line:

```cs
Assertions.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(symbol, nameof(symbol), "Symbol cannot be null or whitespace.");
```

### Extensions

```cs
public static class Assertions
{
    public static void ThrowIfNull<T>(T? value, string paramName, string message = "Parameter cannot be null.") where T : class
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            ThrowArgumentNullException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(string value, string paramName, string message = "String cannot be empty.")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            ThrowArgumentException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty<T>(ICollection<T>? collection, string paramName, string message = "Collection must have elements.")
    {
        if (collection == null || !collection.Any())
        {
            ThrowArgumentException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty<T>(T[]? array, string paramName, string message = "Array must have elements.")
    {
        if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
        {
            ThrowArgumentException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(string value, string paramName, string message = "String cannot be empty or whitespace.")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            ThrowArgumentException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfOutOfRange<T>(T value, T minValue, T maxValue, string paramName, string message = "Value must be within the specified range.") where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(minValue) < 0 || value.CompareTo(maxValue) > 0)
        {
            ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfLessThan<T>(T value, T threshold, string paramName, string message = "Value must be greater than or equal to the threshold.") where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(threshold) < 0)
        {
            ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfLessThanOrEqualTo<T>(T value, T threshold, string paramName, string message = "Value must be greater than the threshold.") where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(threshold) <= 0)
        {
            ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfGreaterThan<T>(T value, T threshold, string paramName, string message = "Value must be less than the threshold.") where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(threshold) > 0)
        {
            ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfGreaterThanOrEqualTo<T>(T value, T threshold, string paramName, string message = "Value must be less than or equal to the threshold.") where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(threshold) >= 0)
        {
            ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfEqual<T>(T value, T target, string paramName, string message = "Parameter cannot be equal to its default value.")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, target))
        {
            ThrowArgumentException(paramName, message);
        }
    }

    [DoesNotReturn]
    private static void ThrowArgumentException(string paramName, string message) => throw new ArgumentException(message, paramName);

    [DoesNotReturn]
    private static void ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(string paramName, string message) => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, message);

    [DoesNotReturn]
    private static void ThrowArgumentNullException(string paramName, string message) => throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName, message);
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is. Why would you expect the debugger to do something different? In particular, `[DoesNotReturn]` is of no interest to it; that's an attribute indicating method behavior to the static analyzer (and note that this attribute merely indicates it, it has no effect on actual runtime behavior). There are other attributes, like `[DebuggerStepThrough]`, that specifically affect the debugger.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIf(...)` doesn't take the debugger to the ArgumentNullException class but it throws on the same line i.e. `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIf(...)`. I want the same behavior for my Assertions class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate `Assertions` class with [`DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute`](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute?view=net-7.0) and then if "Just my code" debugger option is enabled, then debugger will stop not on `throw`, but on the `Assertion.Smth()` call.

For example below debugger will stop on `Assertions.ThrowIfNull` line.

```
Assertions.ThrowIfNull(str, nameof(str), "msg");

[DebuggerNonUserCode]
public static class Assertions
{
   //assertions code here
}
```

If for some reasons you want to "hide" from debugger not the whole `Assertions` class, but only certain members, you can decorate with this attribute only functions you want to "hide".

Additional blog post about this attribute and how to use it with debugger https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015/